# File not saving in images directory

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a file to images directory, but when I press the submit, it not upload, What am doing wrong with php?

this is my uplod.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST["go"]))
{
    echo "Sorry ,could not upload!";
}
else
{    
    $f=$_FILES["uf"]["name"];     
    $path="images/";
    $file=$path.$f;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uf"]["name"],$file);
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you use enctype="multipart/form-data" in Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uf"]["name"],$file);
```

to

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uf"]["tmp_name"],$file);
```

> move_uploaded_file() function doesn't  move the file directly from  form to the new loc, after submitting the form, file is first saved on the temp_directory with tmp_name, and then move_uploaded_file() function moves it to the new location.

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES["uf"]["tmp_name"]` is where the path to the file is stored so you have to use that with `move_uploaded_file`

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uf"]["tmp_name"],$safe_file_name);
```